# Powering my laptop from DC to DC converter?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, voltage

I use my laptop Lenovo Y700 on solar system, but much energy is wasted when converting DC power to AC and then back to DC.

So I bought a 12V DC to 20V DC converter.

Is it safe? Or may it damage my laptop? How to make sure that it is safe?

FYI: I already measured the voltage and it is correct.

Comment: To convert 12 volts DC to a higher DC voltage needs an internal conversion to AC and back. So you probably will not gain much.

Comment: AC to DC conversion *can* be up to 90% efficient, boost converters might also be 90% efficient, but you'll have an additional efficiency loss in converting from AC to DC in the first place.

Comment: What are the voltage and current specification of your laptop power supply. Or what are the specifications of the laptop? If your DC converter produces the same voltage and can provide at least the same current, and if the voltage regulation is good enough (according to the requirements of your laptop) it should be OK.

Comment: @Bodo  i measured the voltage and its right like my original charger  , but the current my laptop charger  is 6A , and on  the DC to Dc is 4A

Comment: The difference in the current specification means, the DC converter may not be able to provide the current needed by the laptop. (I don't know how much current the laptop will actually use under high load.) I would try to get a power supply that is designed for your laptop for use in a car.

Answer (score 0):

A *possible* issue is DC quality. As @Bodo states, the 12 VDC-to-20 VDC supply must provide the same voltage and *at least* the same current as the original power supply. However, it also must be reasonably *pure* DC. Bleed-through of switching spikes or poor regulation can cause problems, ranging from lines or "static" on a display to permanent damage to the PC.

Yes, you lose perhaps 10% to 20% efficiency with up-converting to 120 VAC and back down to 20 VDC, but you'd likely need 120 VAC for any peripheral. In addition, if you used another laptop designed for a different DC voltage or at greater current, you'd need another converter. Your idea is perfectly reasonable, if the supply is capable, but it is not flexible, for that reason.